# DSE graph throwing invalid query exception

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using datastax-5.0.5 version along with client jars with dependencies:        dse-driver (version- 1.1.1-beta1)

and 
   gremlin-driver(version- 3.2.0-incubating)

The following query was giving good results on trying with some 4000 nodes on the graph.:
Query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Person').has('name','Person1').outE('BELONGS').inV().inE('HAS').outV().as('x').inE('HAS').outV().as('y').inE('HAS').outV().has('name','App1').select('x').inE('HAS').outV().hasLabel('Org').as('p').repeat(outE('HAS').dedup().otherV()).until(outE().hasLabel('IS')).has('Asset','name','Asset100').select('y').inE('HAS').outV().hasLabel('Class').repeat(inE('IS').dedup().otherV()).until(inE().hasLabel('HAS')).has('Asset','name','Asset100')
```

But the same is taking long time and giving invalid query exception when tried with some 11million nodes.
Note: The same query is returning good results and with quick time by running it on datastax-studio gremlin-console.

Kindly state what can be the causes for the same ?

Here are the error logs for the same :

```
   Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: 
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
at com.datastax.driver.dse.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:29)
at com.datastax.driver.dse.DefaultDseSession.executeGraph(DefaultDseSession.java:78)
at com.datastax.driver.dse.DefaultDseSession.executeGraph(DefaultDseSession.java:65)
at myGraph.Load.authorizeNodeORFindNode(Load.java:207)
at myGraph.Load.main(Load.java:314)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: 
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:177)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:46)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:797)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:631)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1070)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:993)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1280)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:890)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:564)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:505)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:419)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:391)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:145)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Varun Tahin